# How is the derivative of product of differentiable aplications such codomain is a space of linear transformation?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f: U \rightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $L(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the space of linear transformations of $\mathbb{R}^n$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$, diferentiable and $U \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is open.

Define $f^k(x) = f(x)\cdots f(x)$ ($k$ factors). How is the derivative of $f^k(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

Use the definition of the derivative as the linear map $L(x)$ so that
$$ g(x+h)-g(x) - L(x)(h) = o(\lVert h\rVert ) $$
Then since $f$ is differentiable, we have
$$ f(x+h)=f(x) + Df(x)(h) + o(\lVert h \rVert) $$
Then
$$ f^k(x+h) = \big( f(x) + Df(x)(h) + o(\lVert h \rVert) \big) = f^k(x) + \sum_{n=0}^{k-1} f^n(x) Df(x)(h) f^{k-n-1}(x) + o(\lVert h \rVert), $$
since all the other terms contain at least two $Df(x)(h)$s. Hence the sum is the derivative.